# Chrome inspector stopped working on Android Kit Kat

Tags: android, google-chrome, inspect

I was using Chrome inspector yesterday and it was working fine in developer mode, now today it doesn't inspect just gives me a blank page with no elements or full menu

Here's a  screen shot. Cmd+P does nothing useful either.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/21311ki/8

Comment: I have a brand new Samsung Galaxy Note 4.